# read two text files as an argument and display it's contents using perl

Tags: perl

I have two text files and I want to read them by passing argument at command line.

Now how to take second file? When I give the second file name command line is not reading. Please suggest.

I have used `$ARGV[0]` and `$ARGV[1]` in the code to pass the arguments at command line.

Comment: Post the code that you wrote.

Comment: How are you calling your script from the command line?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
my ($file1, $file2) = @ARGV;
open my $fh1, '<', $file1 or die $!;
open my $fh2, '<', $file2 or die $!;
while (<$fh1>) {
    do something with $_
}
while (<$fh2>) {
    do something with $_
}
close $fh1;
close $fh2;
```

Where `$_` is the default variable.

run as:

```
perl readingfile.pl filename1 filename2
```

Comment: Thanks serenesat. That worked. I finally figured out and have understood. Appreciate your efforts!!

Answer (score 2):

```
$ ./read.pl file1 file2
```

Reading file1
Reading file2

```
$ cat read.pl 
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;

readFile($_) for @ARGV;

sub readFile {
my $filename = shift;
print "Reading $filename\n";

#OPEN CLOSE stuff here

}
```